# Design Automation Inventor shut down error

Tags: autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

I have a working plugin width Autodesk Design Automation API for 2 years and suddenly stop working and throw next error of time out server.

```
[01/11/2023 14:55:28] display name input.iam
[01/11/2023 14:55:28] doc type kAssemblyDocumentObject
[01/11/2023 14:55:28] docdir C:\Users\acesworker\Documents\Inventor Server x64 SDK
[01/11/2023 14:55:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Generate drawing document
[01/11/2023 14:55:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Create a new drawing document
[01/11/2023 14:55:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Get or create a new drawing sheet
[01/11/2023 14:55:28]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Create a base view
[01/11/2023 14:55:33]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Change scale of base drawing view
[01/11/2023 14:55:33]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Create projected view
[01/11/2023 14:55:33]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Create part list
[01/11/2023 14:55:35]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Create Revision table
[01/11/2023 14:55:35]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Done:Create Revision table
[01/11/2023 14:55:35]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Saving IDW C:\Users\acesworker\Documents\Inventor Server x64 SDK\input.idw
[01/11/2023 14:56:36] Error: Inventor Core Engine Core Console is shut down due to timeout.
[01/11/2023 14:56:36] End script phase.
[01/11/2023 14:56:36] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[01/11/2023 14:56:36] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[01/11/2023 14:56:36] Job Status:
```

It's happened when at the last step saving the output file, proved with small files (500Kb) and no intensive process (only open file and save it, no processes needed inside de bundle and the HeartBeat function). It's been working properly a few weeks ago and now throw this error.

Any ideas? Thanks for advance!

**Updates 2023-03-22:**
Finally, I have made it work. I cleaned ActivityIds, AppIds, etc. It seems works but sometimes it resolves with success response and other times it needs 3 o more tries to resolve (even somtimes DA don't achieve give a success result). Here some logs of the results:

```
Create workitem 
21/03/2023 12:54:19 : Workitem id: 11d07facf3ed4cff926a7c70425cc6aa
21/03/2023 12:54:21 : Work item status : inprogress
...
21/03/2023 12:55:42 : Work item status : inprogress
21/03/2023 12:55:44 : Work item status : failedInstructions
21/03/2023 12:55:52 : Create workitem 
21/03/2023 12:55:53 : Workitem id: 210e2c7b8f2f4922be9a7e33cb29e947
21/03/2023 12:55:55 : Work item status : inprogress
21/03/2023 12:55:57 : Work item status : inprogress
...
21/03/2023 12:57:32 : Work item status : inprogress
21/03/2023 12:57:34 : Work item status : success
```

Any new ideas? Thanks at advance

Comment: The path where you try to save IDW document looks strange. This is not a standard working directory for DA. Perhaps there is some new security restriction.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelNavara . The path of the IDW document is used by default by DA in the last 2 years of correct working of our application, and suddenly appears this error.

Comment: Usual path, where you can save your data looks like: `T:\Aces\Jobs\c59d2b7a17724f918758c90e18ee0000\yourFile.txt`. Are you use a project file?